# Slow transactions in sub-domain

Tags: apache-2.2, centos7, php-fpm, plesk

Wonder if you can help solve this little problem.
I administer a system that has Wordpress in the parent domain and an api being served from a sub-domain.
Normally, the api returns results to its client < 1 sec. However, when the api gets 'busy', the transactions appear to queue. We've proved this by the use of timers on the client and on the server. When the server gets a request it processes it < 1 sec and returns data to the client instantly thereafter. When busy it can take 10 sec for the transaction to reach the server process.
Interestingly, this only affects the sub-domain, the primary domain is serving pages with no delays whatsoever.
I'm assuming it is not an application problem as the requests are being returned to client quickly, when they arrive. I'm guessing that it's not an Apache issue as apache is covering at least four domains on the same server and it is only the sub-domain serving the API that is affected.
So, my question is .. where is this delay/queuing occurring? I'm afraid my knowledge of servers & networks has now been exhausted.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of digging in dark holes I think I've solved the issue and wish to pass on in case anyone else gets the issue.
I found that PHP-FPM was causing the issue. Our PLESK managed server has its own PHP environment and PHP-FPM configuration. As traffic built up on the API sub-domain its 'processors' were quickly taken up and a queue formed. However on the parent domain, no effects were seen because not all of its 'processors' were in use.
So a change to the pm.max_children parameter increased the number of 'processors' in the API sub-domain. Of course, use of this parameter should be considered as this will have an impact on the system memory of your server, so don't go mad with it.